Generating text images
I am generating images containing a specific text. There is no problem generating an image with text where all text tokens are from one font. I wanted to bold out some words randomly, which requires me to use (2 fonts) a regular and bold.
Here is my approach for solving this problem:

I split the text into words.
created a font mask randomly wether regular or bold.
I combine all the masks into one image, but, because it is a right-to-left language I had add the masks from the right, one by one.

The problem: is the the words are not on the same horizontal alignment! there is something wrong in combining different masks into one image.

it should be as the following:

from PIL import Image, ImageFont
import random

font_size = 60
font_bold_file = "fonts/Cairo/static/Cairo-Bold.ttf"
font_regular_file = "fonts/Cairo/Cairo-VariableFont_slnt,wght.ttf"
text_color = (0, 0, 0, 255)

font_regular = ImageFont.truetype(font_regular_file, size=font_size)
font_bold = ImageFont.truetype(font_bold_file, size=font_size)

text = "أبت أ ري عالم"
total_x = 0
total_y = 0
segments = []
for w in text.split(" "):

    mask = None
    if random.random() < 1:
        mask = font_regular.getmask(w + " ", "L")
    else:
        mask = font_regular.getmask(w + " ", "L")

    segments.append( (mask, mask.size[0]) )#
    total_x += mask.size[0]
    total_y = max(total_y, mask.size[1])

background_img = Image.new(mode="RGBA", size=(total_x, total_y), color=(255, 255, 0, 255))

acc_widths = 0
for seg in segments:
    mask = seg[0]
    width = seg[1]
    pivot_x = total_x - acc_widths - width
    acc_widths += width

    mask_req = (pivot_x, 0,  pivot_x + width, mask.size[1] )
    background_img.im.paste(text_color, mask_req, mask)


background_img.save("pic.png")



The following code generates this image:

You are using both a static and a variable font. Variable fonts require the static instance of the variation to be specified, otherwise it uses the first instance it finds within the font.
Rather than using masks, I'll take an alternative approach based on an answer to another question and add variable font support to it.
First I define a function to get dimensions to use for the image. This is based on another answer. Since more than one font weight is being used, I have based the dimensions on the primary font and added a fudge factor to accommodate variation.
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
from random import randrange

def get_text_dimensions(text_string, font, fudge=(0, 0)):
    temp_image = Image.new("RGB", (500, 500))
    temp_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(temp_image)
    temp_draw.text((0,0), text_string, font=font)
    bbox = temp_draw.textbbox((0, 0), text_string, font=font)
    # return bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[2] + fudge, bbox[3]
    return bbox[2] + fudge[0], bbox[3] + fudge[1]


You may want to adjust the metrics
In this example, I'll just use the variable font, since it contains both regular and bold instances. There is no need for two separate fonts.
The fudge factor, if required is defined.
I split the words into a list, reverse the list since I am working with RTL text but processing it in visual order.
Then I calculate the horizontal length of a space to use for adjustments later.
text = "أبت أ ري عالم"
font_file = '~/Library/Fonts/Cairo-VariableFont_slnt,wght.ttf'
font_size = 60
dimension_fudge = (6, 3)
tokens = text.split()[::-1]

text_font = ImageFont.truetype(font_file, font_size)
# text_font.get_variation_names()
text_font.set_variation_by_name('Regular')
space = text_font.getlength('\u0020')

I then adjust draw_text_in_font() from answer, adding variable font, direction, and language support, and then adjusting the coordinates to account for whitespace.
The one aspect missing from the function is ability to control opentype features that are applied.
def draw_text_in_font(d: ImageDraw, coords: tuple[int, int], 
    content: list[tuple[str, tuple[int, int, int], str, int, str, str, str]]):
    fonts = {}
    for text, color, font_name, font_size, variant, dir, lang in content:
        font = fonts.setdefault(font_name, ImageFont.truetype(font_name, font_size))
        font.set_variation_by_name(variant)
        d.text(coords, text, color, font, direction=dir, language=lang)
        coords = (coords[0] + font.getlength(text) + space, coords[1])

Then calculate image dimensions and generate a background image, then use draw_text_in_font() to add the text to the image.
dimensions = get_text_dimensions(text, text_font, dimension_fudge)
background_img = Image.new(mode="RGBA", size=(dimensions[0], dimensions[1]), color=(255, 255, 0, 255))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(background_img)

fragments = []
bold_index = randrange(len(tokens))
text_colour = (0, 0, 0)

for i, token in enumerate(tokens):
    instance = "Bold" if i == bold_index else "Regular"
    fragments.append((token, text_colour, font_file, font_size, instance, 'rtl', 'ar'))

draw_text_in_font(draw, (0, 0), fragments)

background_img.save('output.png')

